# How to center div inside div

Tags: html, css, center

Im trying to center the container div within the body2 div. Can someone please help with this?

```
.body2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 40px 100px 100px 490px;  
 } 



.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #1F2937;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;


}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Your question is unclear so far, so please also add more details. Center vertical? center horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

use flex for this

```css
#container{
   width:20%;
   height:20vh;
   border:solid 1px red;
   }
   
#body{
border:solid 1px black;
height:calc(100vh - 4px);
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

body,html{
margin:0;}
```

```html
<div id='body'>
<div id='container'></div>
</div>
```